# Where is my file stored if I write a file using ofstream on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, ofstream

I am using Mac and Xcode for my following code which should get my `cin` value for the `name` and the `age` and write them in the file `fileProcessingTrial.txt`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // insert code here...
    string name;
    int age;
    ofstream fileProcessing("fileProcessingTrial.txt", ios::out);
    cout<<"Please enter your name: "<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Please enter your age: "<<endl;
    cin>>age;
    fileProcessing<<name<<" "<<age<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And then where is my file `fileProcessingTrial.txt` stored (by default?) if I want to open it? Can I store it in a specific location?

Comment: This may depend on your IDE (or at least it does on linux and windows).

Comment: Depends on what the `current working directory` of the application is at the time you write the file.

Comment: Agreed. IDEs typically set the default folder for you and give you an option to change the default in the IDE. Although with that said a program can change its working directory also. However the OP would not be asking if they changed it in code.

Comment: Why not specify the address itself to your `"Whatever\\desiredPath\\fileProcessingTrial.txt"`?

Comment: @drescherjm: Really? What your CWD is might depend on that, but the actual answer ("your CWD at runtime") is determined by the shell used by your OS.

Comment: @FirstStep: Because that's a really evil thing for software to do. We have a _current working directory_ for a reason.

Comment: We have it for a reason and some do not use it for a reason as well. I see a beginner doing a basic application who got an answer + a suggestion @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @FirstStep: You are mistaken. Absolute paths baked into software are most certainly evil. Please do not teach them... especially to beginners, as they don't know any better than to listen to you ;) Also, there are no answers yet.

Comment: @FirstStep saving to a hardcoded location *is* a bad idea. You suddenly depend on that location always existing on all machines where the program runs as well as that location being what users expect on all machines.

Comment: That is why there is a **Documentation** people. A simple "Read Me" or a manual will state which path per which platform and your whole argument is invalid. Please. And you know what, just ask the USER for the desired location. That simple @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: ***determined by the shell used by your OS***  Agreed, However your IDE typically sets this up for you when you press the debug or execute button.

Comment: @FirstStep: Yes, exactly, ask the user. Don't bake it into the code. Glad we agree!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would add an answer specific to Xcode. If you are building and running the executable in Xcode (the IDE), then the output file (if you did not specify an absolute path for the filename) will go to the same directory as the *Build Products* because that is where the built executable will be. This becomes the `current working directory` mentioned by Jesper Juhl when Xcode runs the executable. To locate that, click on the **product** in the **Project Navigator** (in the below screenshot this is the `File Out` executable in the left pane). Then look in the **File Inspector** in the upper right pane. The directory part of the **Full Path** is where your output file is.

[image]

If you did specify a relative path, then the location will be relative to this directory for build products, and as Jesper said, you should avoid encoding an absolute path in your program.

In Xcode, you can also change the `current working directory` by editing the scheme:

1. Go to the *Options* tab under *Run* in the scheme editor.
2. Click on the *Use custom working directory* checkbox
3. Select or enter the working directory (absolute path)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not specify a path (absolute or relative), then the file will be created in the `current working directory` (aka `CWD`) of the application at the time you create the file.

A program can change its CWD with `chdir()` and obtain its current one with `getcwd()`.

It is common for programs to change to some well known directory upon startup and do all their work there if they are daemons.

It is also common for some applications to determine the location of their executable (by reading `/proc/self/exe` on Linux, for example) and then write files to a directory relative to that.

Other commonly used options are; writing to the users home directory or to a directory specified on the commandline or in a configuration file.

When you run a program from the shell, the CWD will initially be the directory the user was in when starting the application.

When running from a IDE, the CWD is usually set by the IDE to some location specified in its configuration.

In any case, avoid hard-coding absolute file paths in your program, since you can never be certain that path exist on all users machines (exceptions exist of course) nor that the user *wants* files written there. Best ask the user one way or another and write files to that location.

Comment: .. and that the user _wants_ files stored at that path, if it does exist. People always forget this: when you write code, you are a _guest_ on the end user's computer.